# ray_cast get all objects?

Tags: scripting

```py
def x_ray_cast(context, depsgraph, origin, direction, ignored_name=[]):
    ray_cast_objs = []
    hide_objs = []
    scene = context.scene
    while True:
        (result, location, _, face_index, obj, _) = scene.ray_cast(depsgraph, origin, direction)
        if not result:
            break
        if obj.name not in ignored_name:
            ray_cast_objs.append({
                "name": obj.name,
                "location": location,
                "index": face_index
            })
        obj.hide_set(True)
        hide_objs.append(obj)

    for obj in hide_objs:
        obj.hide_set(False)
    return ray_cast_objs
```

I need to get all the objects on the ray, and this is how I do it now, is there a better way?

Thanks！

Comment: I've not tested it, but in the principle, that seems to be fine.

Comment: Don't use an empty list as a default argument. See https://nikos7am.com/posts/mutable-default-arguments/

Comment: But to answer your question, I think this makes sense.

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks, I am not a professional programmer, this is the first time I know there is such a problem

Comment: @lemon yes it works fine but i'm not sure if it's good logic

Comment: the logic seems good to me. An alternative should be to recast from the previous hit, but in this case you will hit the same object several times. So what you did is better, I think.